# Multiple context menus in one activity based on selected list view item

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity, android-studio

How can I open different context menus based on the list view item that was selected along with unique if statements within the context menu based on which ever context menu item was selected?

The code below applies for buttons but how can it be done for list view items instead + what I asked for above?

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
        if(v.getId() == R.id.first_button)
             inflate one menu
        else if(v.getId() == R.id.second_button)
             inflate another menu        
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first way:The `ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo` there is extra information about the item for which the context menu should be shown. This information will vary depending on the class of v. so you can do this , copy and paste this

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo info) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, info);        
    int index = info.position; //The position in the adapter for which the context menu is being displayed. 
    View child = info.targetView;//The child view for which the context menu is being displayed. 
    // so for your case you have to use the child,because of your way about it
    if(child.getId() == R.id.first_button)
         inflate one menu
    else if(child.getId() == R.id.second_button)
         inflate another menu        
}
```

let me know if its useful

Comment: Not fully no, need to get IDs for my list view items, not buttons.

Comment: this gets id from the lisview item `child.getId()` and you are saying? if you are referring to R.id.first_button ? well i dont know that id, mine was to answer how to get the specific child and get its id and check so what really are you asking?

Comment: When I type in `R.id.`, none of the IDs for my list view items appear in the menu that pops up - only the ID for my list view does.

Comment: Sir,if you have a textview and you give it an id = `R.id.t1` then the menu that pops up should have t1 as an option, but if it doesn't then either you type the id manually, or maybe it doesnt exist, so check your child id's or clean your eclipse or restart maybe it will re-adjust or something@MacaronLover

Comment: i was assuming if you had, but Sir, if you created your child views programmatically theres a function for view objects which is View.setId(int id); you can put your preffered id there and check it..it should be just an integer.. are you gud now Sir @MacaronLover

Comment: do this in your res -String file paste this code `<item name="textlayid" type="id"></item>` then when you programmatically create a view, setid to `View.setId(R.id.textlayid)`. the in your if statement instead of r.id.button use r.id.textlayid, @MacaronLover